# PHP - Why this returns multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

Hi i have this code and it (records2) returns multi dimensional array for some reason., 
Can someone help me and point out why? i need a simple, single dimension array.

```
function getBook() {
    global $dbc;
    global $id;
    //connect to database
    require('db.php');
    //make the query
    $query = "SELECT title, fiction, publisher, summary, pages FROM bookShelf WHERE id=$id;";
    $runQuery = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query); //run the query


    $records2 = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery)) {
        $records2[] = $row;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($records2);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: since you're just expecting one row, then don't put it inside the while block and don't put any nesting `[]`, just assign it `$records2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery)` like so

Comment: and since you're already using `mysqli`, why not use prepared statements

Comment: Don't make a new connection to the database server every time you need to execute a query. Connect once and reuse the connection.

Comment: ...and don't use `@` to suppress potential error (or other) messages.

Answer (score -1):

```
$records2 = array();
$records2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery);
```

here mysqli_fetch_assoc() function fetches a result row as an single dimension associative array, without any loop.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answers are not appreciated .